# SimpleITK: Rigidly transform image according to 4x4 matrix defined in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, itk, simpleitk

I have an image that I have read using `sitk.ReadImage` and a 4x4 numpy array representing a rigid transform I would like to apply on the image. For the life of me, I cannot seem to figure out how to cast the numpy array to a transform object that is accepted by sitk when trying to perform `sitk.Resample`. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Did you have a look at this: https://simpleitk.org/SPIE2019_COURSE/01_spatial_transformations.html

Comment: If it's a rigid transform, you should be able to construct a SimpleITK Euler3DTransform from it.  Set the rotation matrix from the 3x3 sub-matrix and the translation from the translation vector in the 4x4 matrix.